# Renew login when logged in with cookies and without php session?

Tags: php, cookies

I have a login script with session and cookies,(Remember me) Username, token, selector hashed and set to cookies, but no userID and cookie expire date set to 1 month.

I need to set userID for cookies is well to use it in site to display data,
But setting all critical data to cookies doesn't look right to me.

I can switch userName to userID, but userID is more importand than userName in my site that is why I dont want to make it public.

Require relogin to set php sessions for important pages is an option.

Any other advice ?

All kinds of advice are welcome, Thanks.

Comment: You try to make a sort of `remember me` function for your login page?

Comment: I have `remember me`  option in login script already. example : when I log in with `remember me`, cookies will remember me for 30 days. when ever I return to site cookies log me in with cookie logins credentials. which is username, random selector and token. But no userID, which I am confused if its safe to set username and userID both for cookies.

Comment: What exactly is sensitive about a user id? What can anyone do once they obtain it?

Comment: Never store any data like that in a cookie, How I do it. Create a extra column to your user  table to store a token. The Cookie I create for my user is: user `ip address_user browser agent_random generated key` I encode that string with base64 and store that in the cookie and in the database. When the user go to the login page i check his cookie, decode it and check if the ip is still the same and his browser agent and if his token match the one in the db and get all his user data.

Comment: @El_Vanja UserID is importand when you're using in to display data from database like `$_SESSION['userID'];` in queries, if I get your credentials from cookies then I can edit or change your database. @Baracuda078 I do the same is well and more. Did you try to `echo $_SESSION['userID'];` or `echo $_COOKİE['userID'];` when you log in with only cookies ?

Comment: How is an id part of *credentials*? Username and password are credentials, id should have absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: @El_Vanja You absolutely don't have an idea how important `userID` is when you're using it in queries like `ChangePassword.php?id=1` or similar or any other queries with userID.

Comment: You're completely missing the point. An id is useless to you if you don't have *access* to that page. It's like saying someone can steal all your money just because they have your bank account number.

Comment: You should only use your cookie to indentify the user on the login page, after that u store the data you need in a session from your database